# Dynamic typing or generics in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, generics, plsql

For some reason, I have certain fields in a table, that are collections of chars. Chars of different length. Example:

```
create or replace type t_charray_1 as varray(5) of char(1);
create or replace type t_charray_2 as varray(5) of char(2);
create or replace type t_charray_3 as varray(5) of char(3);
create or replace type t_charray_4 as varray(5) of char(4);

create table mytable (
field1 number,
field2 t_charray_1,
field3 t_charray_3,
```

Also, I have a function that returns a (fixed length) string representation of a `mytable` record. This function calls other functions that are returning the string representation of a given collection-typed field. Examples:

```
  function to_chr(
    p_array in t_charray_1, 
    pad_length in number, 
    p_list_length in number
  ) return char as
    v_res varchar2(255) := '';
  begin
    for i in 1 .. p_list_length loop
      if p_array is not null and p_array.exists(i) and p_array(i) is not null then
        v_res := v_res || rpad(p_array(i), pad_length, ' ');
      else
        v_res := v_res || rpad(' ', pad_length, ' ');
      end if;
    end loop;
    return v_res;
  end to_chr;
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  function to_chr(
    p_array in t_charray_2, 
    pad_length in number, 
    p_list_length in number
  ) return char as
    v_res varchar2(255) := '';
  begin
    for i in 1 .. p_list_length loop
      if p_array is not null and p_array.exists(i) and p_array(i) is not null then
        v_res := v_res || rpad(p_array(i), pad_length, ' ');
      else
        v_res := v_res || rpad(' ', pad_length, ' ');
      end if;
    end loop;
    return v_res;
  end to_chr;
```

Note that these functions are *overloaded* versions of each other. The only difference in their signature is the type of the `p_array` argument.

Please also note that *the bodies of these functions are identical*.

**Motivation**

I want to eliminate duplicate code. What are my choices?

**EDIT** I have heard of sys.anydata but never used it. Can it be a solution?

Comment: how is p_array getting populated?  have u tried creating one varray of varchar2? (and padding the elements as needed)

Comment: That would be a solution If I did not have different collection types but one (lets say, the biggest one). But the different types are needed because they guarantee that e.g. field1 cannot contain values of length bigger than 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a procedure that takes the largest type, and explicitly CAST the smaller types to the larger type before passing them.  Note that CAST can only be used in SQL

```
DECLARE

  x t_charray_1 := t_charray_1();
  y t_charray_2 := t_charray_2();

  PROCEDURE foo( p_foo t_charray_2 )
  AS
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN p_foo.FIRST..p_foo.LAST loop
      dbms_output.put_line( p_foo(i) );
    END LOOP;
  END;

BEGIN
  x.EXTEND;
  x.EXTEND;
  x(1) := 'A';
  x(2) := 'B';

  y.EXTEND;
  y.EXTEND;
  y(1) := 'AA';
  y(2) := 'BB';

  foo(y);

  SELECT CAST(x AS t_charray_2) INTO y FROM dual;
  foo(y);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
create or replace function to_chr(p_array       in anydata,
                                  pad_length    in number,
                                  p_list_length in number) return char as

  v_res varchar2(255) := '';
  x     number;

  v_array t_charray_4;

  v_array1 t_charray_1;
  v_array2 t_charray_2;
  v_array3 t_charray_3;

begin

  dbms_output.put_line(p_array.GetTypeName);
  case p_array.GetTypeName
    when '<schema>.T_CHARRAY_1' then
      x := p_array.GetCollection(v_array1);
      select cast(v_array1 as t_charray_4) into v_array from dual;
    when '<schema>.T_CHARRAY_2' then
      x := p_array.GetCollection(v_array2);
      select cast(v_array2 as t_charray_4) into v_array from dual;
    when '<schema>.T_CHARRAY_3' then
      x := p_array.GetCollection(v_array3);
      select cast(v_array3 as t_charray_4) into v_array from dual;
    when '<schema>.T_CHARRAY_4' then
      x := p_array.GetCollection(v_array);
  end case;

  for i in 1 .. p_list_length loop
    if v_array is not null and v_array.exists(i) and v_array(i) is not null then
      v_res := v_res || rpad(v_array(i), pad_length, ' ');
    else
      v_res := v_res || rpad(' ', pad_length, ' ');
    end if;
  end loop;
  return v_res;
end to_chr;
```

you can run it like this:

```
declare
  p_array anydata;
  v_array t_charray_3 := new t_charray_3('aaa', 'bbb');
  v_res   varchar2(255);
begin
  p_array := anydata.convertcollection(v_array);

  v_res := to_chr(p_array => p_array, pad_length => 2, p_list_length => 3);
end;
```